# Uppercase function but for non alphabetic characters in LUA?

Tags: string, lua, uppercase, love2d

I know that there exists String.upper for the alphabet, but I'm looking for the shift version rather than the alphabetic version, such as the "uppercase" of the semicolon would be the colon. When I attempt to google I get irrelevant results about string.upper.

Comment: Oh, you are talking about the keyboard that you and I are using. Maybe someone who knows love2d could say if it has something built in.

Comment: Are you sure you have not confused anything? Upper case or lower case can be only applied to symbols that can have different case. Punctuation can't have case.

Comment: It depends on locale.  In UK `with_shift['2'] == '"'`, in US `with_shift['2'] == '@'`

Answer (score 6):

I think the best way to handle this would be a lookup table, for example:

```
local with_shift = {
   ["1"] = "!",
   ["2"] = "@",
   ["3"] = "#",
}
```

I haven't been able to find an existing table of this, but I'm sure one exists somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using that for input, you can always check that both the ',' key and the shift key are pressed at the same time - and then execute whatever code you wanted to do.

As others are saying, keyboard layouts are not universal. In a French keyboard, for example, you have to press shift in order to get a '1' when pressing the '1' key in the "top" number row (it defaults to symbols). Neither LÖVE nor Lua know all the keyboard layouts available, and even if they did you could be using a custom-made one (I in fact use one on my computer).